# Error interpreting JPEG image

Tags: gimp, jpeg

I'm trying to upload pictures from a microSD and some pictures uploaded seamlessly, while others did not. All are '.jpg' files.
When trying to open it I received the error:
" "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00"

In terminal, I ran

> file '/media/100GOPRO/G0030191.JPG'
>
> /media/100GOPRO/G0030191.JPG: data

I tried opening it in GIMP

> gimp '/media/100GOPRO/G0030191.JPG'
>
> (gimp:8658): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the JPEG files in question are actually corrupt: they aren't valid JPEG files.

You'd want to troubleshoot more by trying it on a different computer, in a different (micro) SD card reader. If the problem persists, then I'd say the card is at fault, and you should probably get a new card.  If other cards work in the card reader, then there is likely no problem with the card reader.

You can try using Photorec (the file recovery software) to recover more photos from the card but in the case you describe it's unlikely to be useful, as it sounds like the operating system can see all the files in the directory, it's just that some are corrupted.